# How do I get the remaining milliseconds by subtracting 2 dates to be used in a timeOut function?

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I have this code
note that event date is 2018-09-27 and event timeEnd is 18:37

```
let now = new Date();
let eventEnd = new Date(
  `${this.attendanceParameters.attendance_event_date}, 
   ${this.attendanceParameters.attendance_time_end}`);
```

let difference = now.getMilliseconds() - eventEnd.getMilliseconds();

but it returns a relatively small number in a hundredth place when it should atleast return something on the thousandth place

update: here's the full code. Thanks for answering!

```
  hostAttendance() {
    let now = new Date();
    let eventStart = new Date(
      `${this.attendanceParameters.attendance_event_date}, 
       ${this.attendanceParameters.attendance_time_start}`);
    let eventEnd = new Date(
      `${this.attendanceParameters.attendance_event_date}, 
       ${this.attendanceParameters.attendance_time_end}`);
    if (now >= eventStart && now <= eventEnd) {
      this.hostSignInAttendance();
      let difference = (+eventEnd) - (+now);
      console.log(difference);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.hostSignOutAttendance();
      }, difference)  
    }
    else if (now > eventEnd) {

    }
    else if (now < eventStart) {
      this.alert('Event has not yet started', 'Please wait until event has concluded, thank you!', 'Ok');
    }
  }
```

Comment: you're probably looking for the [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getMilliseconds` returns a number between 0 and 999. As in, `5 hours 6 minutes 7 seconds 8 milliseconds` will just return `8` (not `8 + 7 * 1000 + 6 * 1000 * 60 + 5 * 1000 * 60 * 60`).

To get the total number of milliseconds, just cast to a number by adding `+` in front of a date:

```
const date1 = new Date(...)
const date2 = new Date(...)
const diff = (+date2) - (+date1)
```

In the above code, `diff` will the number of milliseconds between two timestamps.

---

Technically, you can also just do `date2 - date1` but that might be a bit misleading since it's an implicit type coercion which you might want to avoid in order not to confuse yourself and others hen reading our code.

Comment: What would the '+' for be? For anti negative difference?

Comment: It's just for casting to number. Try it out in the console: `+new Date()` gives you the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 until the current time.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Nice didn't know either about the + approach! (+1)

Comment: @OlivierKrull `+date1` is a _shortcut_ for `date1.getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply subtracting one date object with another date object returns the difference in milliseconds. Then you can convert those milliseconds to other desired interval.

```js
let now = new Date();
let eventEnd = new Date(
  `2018-09-27, 
   18:37`);
let difference = (+eventEnd)-(+now);
console.log(difference);
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
let difference = now.getTime() - eventEnd.getTime();
```

The getTime method will return a number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)